# Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, shortcode

I am trying to get the slug of a custom taxonomy for  the current post that this shortcode is embedded in if the user doesn't define the slug he wants explicitly in the shortcode.

```
function get_date_posts($params, $content){
        $default_params = array(
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'order'         => 'asc',
            'orderby'       => 'meta_value',
            'posts_per_page'=> 5,
            'meta_key'      => 'fl_date_picker'
        );

        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'calendar_event_type' );
        if ( !empty( $terms ) ){
        $params['slug'] = array_shift( $terms );
        }

//truncated
```

This line is causing the error:  `$params['slug'] = array_shift( $terms );`

Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

How can I get around this? Tried everything to convert this to a string..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify where exactly the error comes from but I assume your problem is that you assign an object to the slug instead of a string. 
your code should look like

```
$t = array_shift( $terms );
$params['slug'] = $t->slug;
```

Comment: Apart from that, `$post` is also an undefined variable in context, failing `$terms`. :-)

Comment: $post seems to work

Comment: @JoannaMikalai, you should still add it as a global or as a parameter to the function. It is possible that it works just because some default handling of error condition gives you the correct result

Comment: ok how can i make it to tie to the argument ''post_type'     => 'post'' ?

Comment: should I just change this to 'post_type' => $post,  ?

Comment: @JoannaMikalai, peter and I are refering to the `$post->ID` you use in ` get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'calendar_event_type' );` while $post is not declared anywhere in your code

Comment: yes, if I make the change I am suggesting, wouldn't that be defined as the choice the user makes in the shortcode ?

Comment: @JoannaMikalai, sorry I don't understand the question but if it is not related to the error maybe it is best to starts a new question.